# X axis labels are not visible in Pivot Dataframe plot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Using a dataframe extracted after doing pivot operation.

```
df['MONTH'] = df['MONTH'].astype(str)

df_month = df.pivot(index='MONTH',columns='INSTRUCTION_TYPE',values='COUNT(*)')
```

[image: Dataframe]

the plot function I am using

```
df_month.plot(figsize=(13, 4))
```

[image: PLot]

The x axis displays only "MONTH". How can I get the exact values in the x-axis?

Comment: Please post more information so that your code is reproducible - or as reproducible as possible. What are the columns of your dataframe? What do you want the x-axis labels to be? Is it only the months of 2018?

Comment: Yes, its a pivot table with huge no of columns, in x-axis I need the values of first column 'MONTHS' like : 201801,201802,201803 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the x-axis without converting 'MONTH' to a time series index, you can use the following code. Set the value of the labels with `ax.set_xticklabels(x)`.

```
ax = df_month.plot(figsize=(13, 4))
x = ax.get_xticks()
print(x)
```

[image]